# select attributes which are a substring of a constant

Tags: database, sqlite

I am faced with a database (sqlite specifically) query that I am not sure how to approach.

I am looking for all tuples who's name attribute is a substring of some provided constant.

For example it is a database containing food items.  If the constant is "Maranatha Natural Almond Butter 26oz Lightly Roasted"  I would like any tuple in the database that contains the words "Almond Butter", "Maranatha Natural", etc to be returned as matches.

I really am at a loss for how to approach this problem efficiently and any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Use `LIKE`, but the other way around:

```
SELECT *
FROM mytable
WHERE 'Maranatha Natural Almond Butter 26oz Lightly Roasted' LIKE '%' || name || '%'
```

Comment: I appreciate the help but Im sorry but this doesnt seem to work, see below. It should have atleast brought up both results `sqlite> SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE 'Maranatha Natural Almond Butter 26oz Lightly Roasted' LIKE '%' || food_name || '%'; 105004|Natural|tbsp|1.0|95.0|4.0|8.0|1.75|0.0|0.0|0.0|3.0|1.0|1.5|75.0|Nuts / Seeds|Skippy|Fat sqlite> select * from tbl where food_name like '%Almond Butter%'; 12195|Almond Butter, Pln, Wo/salt|Cup|1.0|1582.5|37.700001|147.75|14.005|95.934998|31.004999|0.0|53.049999‌​|9.25|0.0|27.5|Nuts / Seeds||Fat`

Comment: `Almond Butter, Pln, Wo/salt` is not a substring of your constant.

Comment: well dont i feel stupid hah, there appears to be a lot more semantics necessary in my search than sqlite will provide, how about something like this.  Count the number of words from the tuple that are present in the constant.  Sorting by the # of word matches in descending order

Comment: That would be a new question.

Comment: thank you for your help thus far, posted up the new question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12627848/select-attributes-in-descending-order-of-of-word-matches-in-comparison-to-a-co

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you give [full-text searching](http://www.sqlite.org/fts3.html) a try. In your examples you wouldn't necessarily need it as `LIKE` might be sufficient. However, if you want to match only exact words (say you search for `set` you may not want `setting` matched) and if you want to match multiple words wherever they appear in your descriptions, FTS can be very helpful. Before using it, verify that your implementation is compiled with it:

```
sqlite> pragma compile_options;
CURDIR
ENABLE_FTS3   <---- this one has to appear
ENABLE_RTREE
TEMP_STORE=1
THREADSAFE=0
```

Say you have the FTS table `FoodItemsFTS` populated with the food item you mentioned earlier:

```
sqlite> CREATE VIRTUAL TABLE FoodItemsFTS USING fts3();
sqlite>
sqlite> INSERT INTO FoodItemsFTS (docid, content) 
        VALUES (1, "Maranatha Natural Almond Butter 26oz Lightly Roasted");
sqlite> INSERT INTO FoodItemsFTS (docid, content) 
        VALUES (2, "Maranatha Natural Almond Butter 26oz");
sqlite>
sqlite> SELECT docid FROM FoodItemsFTS WHERE FoodItemsFTS MATCH 'Almond Roasted';
1
sqlite>
```

Comment: thanks a lot @Ludo but I think you have the idea of my contants and tuples switched around.  For my situation the shorter string, i.e. 'Almond Roasted' would be already stored in the database and you would want to get the stored results that are a substring of the longer, "Maranatha Natural Almond Butter 26oz Lightly Roasted" which is the constant.