# Select attributes in descending order of # of word matches in comparison to a constant

Tags: sqlite

I am faced with a database (sqlite specifically) query that I am not sure how to approach.

I'm looking for all tuples that have 1-n word matches between their 'name' attribute and a constant.  Sorted in descending order.

For example it is a database containing food items. If the constant is "Maranatha Natural Almond Butter 26oz Lightly Roasted" I would like any tuple in the database that contains atleast one of the words in that constant to be returned. For example "Almond Butter Natural" would come before "Maranatha Natural" which would come before "Almond", etc.

Essentially as long as there is one intersecting word between the tuples attribute and the constant it qualifies a match.

Answer (score 0):

Matching words is what SQLite's [full-text search extension](http://www.sqlite.org/fts3.html) is designed for. Please read that page to see how SQLite must be compiled and what is possible, but I'll add some remarks:

Simple matching is done with a query like:

```
SELECT * FROM foods_fts_tab WHERE name MATCH 'Maranatha Natural Almond etc.'
```

This will just return all records where at least one word matches.

You can weight the matches with information returned by the auxiliary functions.
For example,

```
SELECT ... ORDER BY length(offsets(foods_fts_tab)) DESC
```

will sort by the number of matching words.

You are asking for the number of word matches, but real search engines also use other information to compute relevancy scores. See the `matchinfo()` function in section 4.3 and the example in appendix A.